# Find polynomial of degree n+1 for n+1 data points.

Tags: linear-algebra, interpolation

Generally, if we have ***n+1*** data points, there is exactly one polynomial of degree at most n going through all the data points. What can we tell about existence of polynomial of degree ***n+1***? How can we find polynomial of degree ***n+1*** for a table:

**x**: 0 1  2  3

**y**: 1 0 -5 -20

Comment: Add a point with an arbitrary value and compute that one. In particular, deduce that you have at least as many polynomials as you have potential values for another input.

Comment: P.S. You never say what $n$ is for the one you want. Also, here’s a [MathJax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Please use MathJax to format your posts.

Comment: Given your $n+1$ values for $x,$ you can create a plynomial of arbitrarily large degree for which all  $f(x_j) = 0.$ Then add that to your original. You may take any $$ f(x) = (x-x_1)(x-x_2) ... (x-x_{n+1}) g(x) $$  where $g(x)$ is any polynomial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a set of points $\{(x_1,y_1,\ldots,(x_{n+1},y_{n+1})\}$. Construct a polynomial $p_n(x)$ of degree $n$ going through the points. Then you can find a polynomial of any degree $n+k$ going through that set of points. You could, as Arturo points out, add any $k$ points, distinct from your original set, to the set of points then find a polynomial of degree $p_{n+k}(x)$ going through those points using your method of choice. Then you have a polynomial of degree $n+k$ going through your original points.

If $k$ is particularly large, you could do this with the method above coupled with multiplying $p_n(x)$ by a polynomial which interpolates the points $\{(x_1,1),\ldots,(x_n,1)\}$ (so that it increments the degree but does not change the value of $p_n(x)$ at your $x_i$'s).

As another method, you find a polynomial of degree $k$, say $g(x)$, and then form
$$
\tilde{p}(x)= p_n(x) + g(x) \prod_i (x-x_i)
$$
so that $\tilde{p}(x)$ takes the values $y_i$ at each $x_i$ but is of degree $\deg p_n(x) + \deg g(x)= n+k$